# How to specify cost attributes for network analysis in QGIS using the GRASS plugin?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, network

I have a road dataset with information about the length, speed and drivetime for each segment. I use QGIS 1.9 with the GRASS plugin to do different types of network analysis, but how do I set up the drivetime attribute as the cost for my analysis? Or perhaps the road length?

In GRASS 6/7 you can specify this column when you do the analysis, but not in the GRASS plugin in QGIS? The same applies to my road directions, how can I take into consideration one way streets, which I have information about in the attribute table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the GRASS plugin in QGIS is too limited if you cannot specify the column? If so, you should file a bug with the QGIS plugin developers...

Comment: user21965: It looks like you're right. I agree with @markusN that it's a bug. Luckily you can do this easily via command line (see http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/v.net.iso.html) and still visualize results in QGIS :)